# why there is a integer overflow in this multiplication?

Tags: c++

I am puzzled on this code snippet:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "long max " << LONG_MAX << endl;
    long x = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    cout << "2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting **2147483648** as it should be, instead I am getting. Using unsigned doesn't seem to help. what gives?

```
long max 9223372036854775807
2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = -2147483648
```

Comment: if you type `1024`, it already has a data type, in this language being integer. That is why you need to specify `1024L` if you want long datatype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add some `L`s*. `long x = 2L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;`

(Technically, as long as one literal is of type `long` the others will be promoted to `long`)

The overflow happens because `2`, etc. is of type `int` by default and the overflow happens *before* the assignment.

See [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) which explains the different literals.

Comment: And the signed int has a maximum of `(2^31) - 1`, so `2^31` overflows that by one. (just to make it more complete).

Comment: I mistakenly thought the upcast will take care of it, apparently not. thx

Comment: @Oliver: The overflow happens before the assignment. Also, note that signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: `long` is still only a 32-bit type on some systems; use `LL`.  Also, the *first* or *second* literal has to be `long`, promotion happens during evaluation of each `*`.  On a system with 16-bit `int`, `2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L` would have already overflowed `int` before evaluating the last `* 1024L` that forces promotion of the left hand side to `long`.